# qmake install ignores android /res folder

Tags: android, qt, qmake

I found out that I can use `INSTALLS` to replace `ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR`. But for some reason it ignores `/res` folder.

My project has 2 android related folders. `/android` and `/android_extra`.
At first it was all one folder that was included in the build with `ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR`, but that's not the best solution, since some files, depending on the build, shouldn't be included.
So I put the optional files inside `android_extra`.

If I use the `ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR` for the mandatory `/android` folder and `INSTALLS` for the optional `/andorid_extra` it doesn't include the `/android_extra/src`  files.

If however I use `INSTALLS` instead of  `ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR` it doesn't include the `android/res` files, but the `/android_extra/src` will be included...

I don't know what else to try, mainly I'm just looking at how the build system is making fun of me...
Any solution to this, or how to force it to include files?

I also noticed that if I put the `INSTALLS path` to `/res2` it will copy the files, so I assume it can't copy to `/res`. Probably the same case is for `/src` with ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR. Is there some "write protection"?

This is the code part in my `.pro` file:

```
# ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR = $$PWD/android
# can be repalced by
    ANDROID_SOURCES.path = /
    ANDROID_SOURCES.files = $$PWD/android/*

    INSTALLS += ANDROID_SOURCES

vmxBuild {
    VMX_SOURCES.path = /
    VMX_SOURCES.files = $$files($$PWD/android_extra/VmxPlayer/*)

    INSTALLS += VMX_SOURCES
}
```

The compile output seems normal:

```
qmake -install qinstall /home/user/Projects/myProject/android/res /home/user/Projects/build-myProject-Android_for_arm64_v8a_Clang_Qt_5_12_5_for_Android_ARM64_v8a-Debug/android-build/res
The process "/home/user/Android/android-ndk-r19c/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/make" exited normally.
```

Comment: try removing the * from $$PWD/android/*

Comment: Sadly it's not so simple. Turns out, `androiddeployqt` is at fault here. It removes the folders/files that are in the project but not in `Qt/5.12.5/android_arm64_v8a/src/android/templates/res`

Comment: Made a workaround by building custom `androiddeployqt` that ignores the `cleanAndroidFiles(options)` which deletes the files.